# Add method to standard class inside a module

Tags: ruby, module

I want to add new method to class `String`, for example. But I don't want to make this change global (keeping classes clean is good, yes?).

So, instead of this code

```
class String
  def is_palindrome?
    self == self.reverse
  end
end

module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def filter_palindrome(str_arr)
      str_arr.select { |s| s.is_palindrome? }
    end
  end
end
```

I want to have something like this:

```
module MyModule
  class String
    def is_palindrome?
      self == self.reverse
    end
  end

  class MyClass
    def self.filter_palindrome(str_arr)
      str_arr.select { |s| s.is_palindrome? }
    end
  end
end
```

But, of course, it's not working (`undefined method 'is_palindrome?' for :String`). So, is there any point in what I want? And if there is, what is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 2.0, you can try [refinements](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec).

```rb
module MyModule
  module StringAlter
    refine String do
      def is_palindrome?
        self == self.reverse
      end
    end
  end
end

using MyModule::StringAlter
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def self.filter_palindrome(str_arr)
      str_arr.select { |s| s.is_palindrome? }
    end
  end
end
```

If prior to Ruby 2.0, you cannot achieve this directly. Changes made to String will be global. However, instead of `s.is_palindrome?`, why not write a helper method and call it like `is_palindrome?(s)`. Then you don't have to reopen `String` and you can restrict `is_palindrome?` to be available only in some given scope.

This is the way Python does (`self`), and so as to C# extension method.

Comment: Refinement seems to be the thing. Thanks.